# One AirPod stop working when pushing both

Tags: airpods

That is really strange and interesting and was reproduced on every AirPods I've seen.

If you are using both AirPods and then start pushing them into your ears with your palms (like in this [photo](https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/tired-red-haired-guy-covering-ears-with-palms-picture-id916040122)):

1. For some time sound will start jumping from one ear to another.
2. One AirPod will stop working.
3. If you remove this AirPod from your ear music will not be paused.
4. Put it back then in some time it will be back to work.

Any ideas what is the reason for this effect?

Comment: Is pushing them in with your palms stated in the instructions as how to use them?

Comment: @SolarMike that how I prevent them from dropping out time to time. It is not hard push, but really gentle and soft push.

Comment: pushing with the palms is not normally equated with soft and gentle - that is what finger-tips are designed for...

Comment: @SolarMike, we can discuss a lot that, but finger-tips are not always convinient for that, and you can really do it softly by your palms, like on the picture in the question.

Main question is — what is the reason of this effect and why it is happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it is a known issue and that is a reason to get AirPods replaces, if the issue is confirmed in a service center.

https://support.apple.com/airpods-pro-service-program-sound-issues